# Unable to use dynamic JSON

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

am using ajax request for calling jersey restful url.

```
function deRegisterPersonOrganization() {
    var dynamicJson = $('#jsonRequest').val();
    alert("Text Area JSON : " +dynamicJson);
    var jsonObj = {
        "solutionProviderKey" : "e3fad159-ac18-462d-a20e-17763af3689b"
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: rootURL + '/e3fad159-ac18-462d-a20e-17763af3689b/deregister',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(dynamicJson),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Deregister successfull');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Deregister error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is i need to give the JSON request where i will give it through the text area.
in the above code if i use variable jsonObj in the place of dynamicJson the request is successful. but if i use dynamicJson where in the textarea i give

```
{
   "solutionProviderKey" : "e3fad159-ac18-462d-a20e-17763af3689b"
}
```

as request, unable to process request.

Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the string into a json object.

```
var dynamicJson = JSON.toJSON($('#jsonRequest').val());
```

KJ

Comment: Thanku so much.. this works. also $.parseJSON($('#jsonRequest').val()) works.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because the value from textarea is a string, not a JSON object. I would suggest:

```
var dynamicJson = eval(textarea.value);
```

and then pass the dynamicJson into the method call as it is now.

Comment: Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: Yes. it is just one suggestion way to turn a string into JSON object. I can see you suggest another way from answer. Thank for the comment.

Comment: this doesnt work. the request is changed to form submit event here.

Comment: But i got an idea that the string should be converted to json from your answer. thanks anyway :)